# Dynamic to Custom C# Object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, dynamic, deserialization

I am trying to convert dynamic object contains JSON data into custom c# object and get the following error:

> RuntimeBinderException The best overloaded method match for
>   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, System.Type,
>   params Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter[])' has some invalid arguments

The variable named `communication` is a `dynamic` object contains the following value (JSON data):

```
{
  "name": "inGame",
  "selected": true,
  "image": "assets/img/communication/ingame.png"
}
```

here is the code that should convert the dynamic into a custom c# object:

```
InGameCommunication  inherited = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(communication, typeof(InGameCommunication),
                                                          new JsonSerializerSettings());
```

**The class hierarchy:**

```
public abstract class Communication
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}

public class InGameCommunication : Communication
    {
    }

public class SkypeCommunication : Communication
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But what is `communication` at runtime?

Comment: Have another look in my question, I've wrote its runtime value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've stated that `communication` is a `dynamic` object. However, that does not absolve you of type-safety. At run-time `communication` still needs to be a string (As stated in the error message).

You're bypassing compiler error by making the variable `dynamic` but at run-time if the variable isn't a string or of a conversion that can be inferred it will still throw.

See the [msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx), specifically the heading on overload resolution.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks like it should work. Can you show how you declared the variable `Type`?

It should be something like

```
var type = typeof(InGameCommunication);
```

Comment: Yes, its the same way I've declared my type variable. I've updated my post with this value.